# DMing without any resources: Is this DND anymore?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dice, books

I have a DM who doesn't use a map or minis, rarely uses our stats, and usually only uses rolls. *Sometimes* he uses a book. Most of the time he's really only telling a story, and we're telling it with him. In other words, he uses very few actual DND resources. I'm wondering the *exact formula* for a DND game. What is it, specifically, that makes an RPG DND, instead of any other RPG, or just a story?

What DND stuff do I need to make it DND, physical or otherwise?

Comment: It may not be D&D, but it sounds like it still might be quite fun.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about D&D, or more generally about the difference between role-playing games vs improvisational theatre or "lets pretend" and the like?

Comment: The difference between theatre and/or other games and actual DND.

Comment: I ask because there's a big difference in answers between "Is this D&D?" and "Is this a tabletop role-playing game?" There are a lot of RPGs which look much different from D&D.

Comment: Is this question more like “How much can you ignore the rules of D&D before it's not ‘D&D’ anymore?”?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have a real problem to be solved and just wants discussion and opinions, which does not fit our site format.

Comment: Perhaps a little of that, but mostly: What DND stuff do I need to make it DND, physical or otherwise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The described style of play falls within what E. Gary Gygax or Dave Arneson would have accepted as D&D.

Mention is made in various writings of theirs of sessions that proceeded in such a manner. There is no hard and fast requirement for maps or minis, tho' 3rd, 4th and 5th editions' combat mechanics generally presume their use.

Occasional rolls, if based upon the mechanical premises of the edition in use, also don't kick it out of the "Still D&D" range.

As a D&D Dungeon Master, I generally don't look at character sheets, so that's not a big issue, either.

So, it boils down to these elements:

- Does it have a D&D type setting?
- Do the players make use of D&D mechanics to influence their choices?
- Does the game in play use the typical race and class based tropes?

If it does, it's probably still within the scope of what Gygax or Arneson would call D&D.

Whether anyone else who plays D&D would recognize it as such is a different matter, but again...

- Does it use a D&D type setting?
- Are there d20's in use?
- Are the races and classes consistent with their typical D&D prototypes?

If so, then it's likely to be recognized as at least a form of D&D play.

Comment: Is Vancian magic enough of a core issue to make your list of "boil-down elements"? Not so much the daily preparation, at least for many casters, but the slots and levels at least?

Comment: @nitsua60 well, 4e does away with the so-called "Vancian magic" (which is not really how magic worked in Vance's books, hence the quotes), and I mean with spell slots of different levels, and it's still recognizably D&D.

Comment: For me, no. Vancian magic is gone from 4th and 5th ed, and there was a spell point option in several editions. It's one of the parts of "Is it a D&D type setting" but not a firm enough part to be definitive if its missing.

Comment: Breaking a post's legibility is not a valid reason to use editing or rollback features, regardless of authorship.

Comment: A change that makes no change is not a valid edit, SSD. It was WORD FOR WORD.

Comment: But an edit that makes no change won't save, so when it seems like that's happened, I make the safe assumption that I'm missing something. If we compare the revisions, the difference is a format-significant newline, making the second list render properly instead of flowing up into the preceding paragraph. It's easily overlooked when just looking at the side-by-side markdown view of a revision, granted. When I don't immediately understand why an edit has been made by comparing the sources, I find it useful to check other views or even open each revision's direct link and compare them manually.